# Upgrade High-Trust Addin/App from 2013 to 2016

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, upgrade

I have a SharePoint 2013 environment with several High-Trust Addins. This must now be upgraded to SharePoint 2016.

**My Questions:**

1. I was unable to find any documentation on the required steps. Links are welcome.
2. Do i have to migrate App-Management Service and Subscription Settings Service? [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-service-applications-to-sharepoint-server-2016) don't even mention them.  [Technet Forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a151c32-4c77-4fe9-abe0-f41a174bd325/migrating-sharepoint-hosted-apps-from-sharepoint-2013-to-2016?forum=sharepointgeneral) say yes, but linked background is no longer available.
3. [During initial setup on SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shariq/2013/05/07/how-to-set-up-high-trust-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-troubleshooting-tips/), i had to create a `New-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer`. In this step, a `RegisteredIssuerName` had to be specified. This `IssuerName` consists of the `Realm` and the [`IssuerID`](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-issuer-id-for-provider-hosted-addin-in-sharepoint-2016).

   - I think `IssuerID` can and should be migrated to SharePoint 2016, as it it also defined inside the High-Trust app.
   - What about the `Realm`? This is by default the same value as FarmID. If i migrate this value, i have to change the Realm in SharePoint 2016. Or should i create the TST with a new `Realm` and existing `IssuerID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this question on my own:

1. Still no documentation available. I think Microsoft completely missed that! All info is from my own trial-and-error. **Follow it completely on your own risk!**
2. Service-Applications:

   - We didn't move Subscription-Settings-Service to the new farm. Reason is the `Versions` table in the according database. The `Version` row seems to contain a Update-Installation history of the specific farm. We didn't want to replace that in 2016 with the values of 2013.
   - AppManagementService had to be migrated. Without migration, we got the error `App "i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|<appid>@<realm>" is not available.` when loading the app on the site. I think there is some important stuff in `AM_AppPrincipals` and `AM_AppPrincipalAppInstances` tables. Migration is done like most other Service-Applications:

     - Backup ServiceApplication-Database in old SQL-Server and restore to new SQL.
     - If exists: Delete existing AppManagementService in SP2016
     - Create new AppMgmt-Service with `New-SPAppManagementServiceApplication -Name "<YourName>" -Database <YourRestoredDatabaseName> -ApplicationPool <YourAppPool>`
     - Create Proxy with `New-SPAppManagementServiceApplicationProxy -Name "<YourProxyName>" -ServiceApplication <YourAppManagementService>`
3. We found an interesting article related to [Realm-Change when configuring SPO-Hybrid-Environment](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4010011/provider-hosted-add-ins-stop-working-and-http-401-error). The information there is highly useful, as it describes how a Realm-Change for existing High-Trust-Apps has to be handled.

   - Based on that article, we decided to keep the Realm from SP2013 in SP2016. So we copied the SP2013 Realm to our SP2016 environment with the `Set-SPAuthenticationRealm` cmdlet.
   - `IssuerID` remained the same, as it is defined inside the app
   - So we created the `New-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer` with `-RegisteredIssuerName <oldIssuerID>@<oldRealm>`